# Iteration of an integer

Tags: java

I have homework on writing a program which intakes X amount of years then asks for input for each month based on how many years were inputted (e.g.1 year requires 12 data inputs (one for each month)). How to generate such code?

Comment: Yep. Open your IDE and start coding.

Comment: Do you have problems with reading an input, writing a loop, or multiplying by twelve?

Comment: im just unsure how i would start it, would i set a value to 12 then multiply that based on the input of years? in saying that how would i then state the year # and month # for each input?

Comment: Please, take a quick tour at stackoverflow.com/tour and check how to ask properly.

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help you with programming problems with code you ***already*** have, not to produce code for you. Give the problem a try and if you're stuck, then post the code that doesn't work here with a specific question about it.

Comment: im not asking for code im asking for  it can be done. Everyone is giving criticism yet no one has pointed out how this can be done.

Comment: Yes, this trivial homework assignment is in fact possible to complete. We haven't explained how because that's not how this website works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use simple math in Java.
Example:

```
int peopleAmount = 3;
int money = peopleAmount * 5;
System.out.println(money); //Would print 15
```

This example would calculate the money I would need if I give 3 people each 5$. You can easily adapt that example.

---

I know it can be hard to learn a programming language, but you should learn (at least) the basics, like calculating with integers, doubles...

I would recommend SoloLearn. They have **free** apps for Android, iOS and even Windows Phone. Just download "Learn Java" and learn the basics of Java. Please don't ask people on StackOverflow for help in terms of Java basics. This is a community for more complex questions.